# Ubuntu 16.04 rPi3 image resize

Tags: ubuntu

Attempt to perform flash [resize procedure](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Root_resize) failed (could not reboot) and forced the reinstall of the [Ubuntu image](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz).

After reinstalling the image:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1). Changes will remain in memory
only, until you decide to write them. Be careful before using the
write command.


Command (m for help): p Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.7 GiB, 31914983424
bytes, 62333952 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector
size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size
(minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk
identifier: 0xc7079672

Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *      8192   270335   262144  128M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      270336 62333918 62063583 29.6G 83 Linux
```

Does this snippet indicate that all 32GB of the microSD card is allocated?

```
Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *      8192   270335   262144  128M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      270336 62333918 62063583 29.6G 83 Linux
```

In the future, can I use the above specs to format the SD card with GPARTED before writing the image to the SD card? or does that have to be done with GPARTED after writing the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually followed the (unfortunately poorly explained) resize process it should have worked. (It has each time I have done it.) You probably did something wrong - the `fdisk` prompts are easy to get wrong.

If you are writing an image to the card it makes NO DIFFERENCE how the card is formatted, or indeed if it is formatted at all.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that you performed the process according the link and that it works \ is correct.  I tried 3 times and I borked it up.